# Fetch data from two table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails3. I have two table `user_shift` and other is `shift` table . I want current shift of the particular user. `user_shift` table field  are

```
`id`, 
`from`, 
`to`, 
`shift_id`, 
`user_id`, 
`created_at`, 
`updated_at`
```

and in `shift` table fields are

```
`id`, 
`start_time`, 
`end_time`, 
description`, 
`created_at`, 
`updated_at` .
```

Comment: Please go through Joins... Which db are you using

Comment: @AnuragShukla : It is already specified in the question. mysql

Comment: I know but it is special case @AnuragShukla

Answer (score 3):

MySQL joins are the best solution for this.

**Example**

```
SELECT * FROM shift LEFT JOIN user_shift ON shift.id = user_shift.shift_id
```

**Shift with user**

```
SELECT * FROM shift LEFT JOIN user_shift ON shift.id = user_shift.shift_id WHERE user_shift.user_id = LOGGEDINUSERID
```

Comment: This query is ok but i need when current shift means when user login he can see current shift. According to your query he can see all shift data  lol :)

Comment: @Abhishek see now i have added new query for that.

Comment: Hey man ! suppose that particular user has multiple shift then how can he get latest current shift

Comment: @Abhishek you can use order by clause to short record according to shift created DESC and set limit to 1 so you will get only latest record.

Comment: Oh! many many thanks i got what i need .Actually i was thinking in wrong direction.Your last comment came to me on track. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT us.id, s.start_time, s.end_time 
FROM user_shift us, shift s
WHERE us.shift_id = s.id AND us.id=?;
```

Comment: Why are you not using `JOIN`:s?

Comment: I have used join without specifying the join keyword.

Comment: This query is ok but i need when current shift means when user login he can see current shift. According to your query he can see all shift data .